# Jssor slider - image shake bug

Tags: slider, jssor

I use jssor slider, very nice library, but I have sometimes problem with little image shake, after effect is finished or when is hovered by mouse.

This shake (or movement) shows only sometimes - not for all images.

I see this also in demo pages, when slideshow is smaller than images.
Check this demo in firefox and window size 333x600 (width is important, you can set window size by CTRL+SHIFT+M)
http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-slider.html

Not all values of width can reproduce this bug, but important is that slideshow width is smaller than image files.

Comment: I can't see an option of 333x600

Comment: there are 320x480, 360x640 ...

Comment: in this mode just resize window by mouse to set to any value

Comment: this shake (movement) is only about 1px-2px, but is visible

Comment: ok, let me check it out. Many thanks!

Comment: I found problem. Is caused by browser antialising. If I turn off by css image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; then no movement is appeared but images is terrible. I found workaround: set FAKE transform to image, transform: translateX(0px);  problem is that plugin set on some temporary images inline transform:none...and my css is overwriten

Comment: I see. Great job! So, anything I can do?

Comment: I overwrite $JssorUtils$.$SetStyleTransform and $JssorUtils$.$DisableHWA to do nothing. I use only fade effect and seems this is not needs for it. I have one more problem in fade effect. If slideshow goes from landscape to portrait image than old landscape image doesn't fadeout, just hide (also without my hack code)

Comment: Would you please leave an url of the sample? And it happens with firefox only?

Comment: happens in all browsers, for sample I use your demo code, but I change pictures and set FillMode to 1   http://roborobo2.tym.sk/jssor/examples/slider-with-slideshow.source.html

Comment: I checked your sample, and read comments in the page. You need to modify source code to prevent image from display before image loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Define all your imag as lazy loading image (e.g. ).
Open jssor.slider.js, find following code at line 1515, and move it to line 1377.

```
                    $JssorUtils$.$Each(_ImageElmts, function (imageElmt) {

                        if (!imageElmt.src) {
                            imageElmt.src = $JssorUtils$.$GetAttributeEx(imageElmt, "src2");
                            $JssorUtils$.$SetStyleDisplay(imageElmt, imageElmt["display-origin"]);
                        }
                    });
```

I got your concern exactly now.

The best way to get it work as you want is to manually set image size by yourself.
e.g.

```
<img src="url" style="position: absolute; top: ...px; left: ...px; width: ...px; height: ...px" />
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I found solution for missing fadeOut. I use transition { $Duration:2000, $Opacity:2, $Brother:{ $Duration:2000, $Opacity:2 }}. To fix image showing your patch doesn't work, I give errors in console. http://roborobo2.tym.sk/jssor/examples/slider-with-slideshow.source2.html

Comment: this is ugly solution and doesn't work. I upload very big first image to better see loading progress. http://roborobo2.tym.sk/jssor/examples/slider-with-slideshow.source3.html. You does not react to lazy loading bug - repeated loading previously loaded images.

Comment: Image size is unknown before load. Anyway, you can set size for each image manually. Also, config your server to enable client cache for images to prevent from image reloading.

Comment: Any idea? Anything I can do for you?

Comment: Actually do not anything yet. No working solution. Image size is already set, see source code for first image. On my own server I have also  Cache-Control:max-age=315360000, but jssor plugin reloads image ever and ever, mostly in case manual swipe to back image. Ideally I want hide images before are loaded. I could do this myself if $EVT_LOAD_END work properly.

Comment: No such problem for my website. btw, would you please have a simple test (with no slider) to see if your 'Cache-Control:max-age=315360000' works?

Comment: No, my server is now only on localhost. Why plugin loads from server image that is already loaded and img tag has filled src attribute?. Your solution is only workaround. Why has corrupted $EVT_LOAD_END? Why you haven't at least one skin and option for slideshow with play/pause button?

Comment: I found that image reload only happens with chrome + local host server. Anyway, no worry. It would be ok after you upload your work on internet.

Comment: Most people don't need play/pause button. So I don't want to increase the load of javascript. And it's easy to implement it manually by end user.

Comment: Ok, I will trust you. Yours online demo pages also read images repeatedly, but there is missing cache.

Comment: Please let me know which page with what kind of browser/version?

Comment: for example this http://jssor.com/demos/x-fade.html, Firefox 29.0.1, used firebug, screen: http://roborobo2.tym.sk/jssor/firebug.jpg. It happens after pause/play on hover or manual swipe

Comment: No reloading found with double check. Maybe browser settings problem.

Comment: I checked it in 2 ways. 1. check with no firebug (just press F12). 2. check with firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same image files for your thumbnails as your main images. Use a separate, smaller version. I had the same issue and that fixed it.