# jssor slider weird image size behaviour and white spacing with chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, jssor

I seem to have a bug with the jssor slider - which seems to be limited to chrome at the moment.

My first problem is similar to - [Jssor slider - image shake bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725084/jssor-slider-image-shake-bug) - where the image shrinks every time just before the transition animation is played and expands just after the transition animation ends. I've seen it happen on chrome and firefox but funnily enough it doesn't happen on IE10. Would the person who figured out the problem explain more in depth on what had to be changed to fix this issue?

My other problem is quite big as it breaks the website completely by hiding my page content with big white spaces. By chance i happened to have 21 images showing for the slider and when in chrome, every time the transition animation would be played, i would get the whole height of the slider (i.e. all content that is right next to the slider, imagine on this website, the orange right side element next to this current text element) turn white with nothing showing until the animation ends. I have tried to see if this happens on any other browsers but it seems to be chrome only for now.

Now an even more stranger behaviour happens when i scroll down the page to a certain position (it's always at this position), the whole screen turns white except for the slider. When i scroll the page down slightly more, then the page content returns! I've tried looking at developer tools and i see all my content is there as i can select the elements and their positions when i hover over them.

I have no idea why this is happening or even begin to search what could be causing this.

Comment: Can you please share your code through jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: I have added images here to show the problem - 
http://imgur.com/a/Ohzd2#0

Answer (score 1):

Please set $HWA option to false to disable hardware acceleration and have a test. It happens seldom in large page with chrome only.

Comment: ah i see, disabling this has removed the white box problem and also the image resizing problem. But having this removed has slowed down the rendering of the slideshows considerably. Thanks for the tip but im wondering, is this going to be fixed or is this a chrome issue?

Comment: It happens only with chrome. I will look for better solution possible.